# How to create conditional logic link with drop-down field in html?

Tags: html, forms, button, hyperlink

How to create conditional logic link with drop-down field in html? eg drop down field= item1,  item2 and suit button link based on item1=url1 or item2=url2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make dropdown with link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500829/how-to-make-dropdown-with-link)

Comment: Following code works fine but how to add submit button with this code.     
    <form >
    <select name="forma" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="http://surtymar.com/fr/reglementation-internationale/">Réglementation internationale 15</option>
        <option value="http://surtymar.com/fr/reglementation-union-europeenne/">Réglementation 15</option>
    </select>
</form>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic example showing how to redirect the browser to the url selected from a dropdown among a list of options, when the form gets submitted.

This demo adds a `submit` event listener to the `#mainForm` when the page has loaded, that will cancel the default behaviour with `event.preventDefault()` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)) and will visit the page at the url defined in the selected option ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)).

Plus the dropdown itself listens for the `change` event printing on console the latest url selected and enabling the submit button as soon as a valid option was chosen.

Two ways to listen to events were showed here... both with `addEventListener` and with the `onchange` html attribute in the declarative way.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  const mainForm = document.getElementById('mainForm');
  mainForm.addEventListener('submit', (event)=>{    
    event.preventDefault();    
    const url = fetchSelectedUrl();    
    location.assign(url);    
  });
});

function fetchSelectedUrl(){
  document.querySelector('#mainForm button[type=submit]').removeAttribute('disabled');
  const url = document.getElementById('urls').value;  
  console.log(`Selected url: ${url}`);
  return url;
}
```

```css
label{
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#urls{
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

form{
  width: 50%;
}

.row{
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.row > *:nth-child(1){
  flex: 25%;
}

.row > *:nth-child(2){
  flex: 75%;
}

.submit{
  text-align: right;
}

button[type=submit]{
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form id="mainForm">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="urls">Select a page to visit:</label>
    <select id="urls" onchange="fetchSelectedUrl();">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select an option</option>
      <option value="https://google.com">Google (com)</option>
      <option value="https://google.de/">Google (de)</option>
      <option value="https://google.fr">Google (fr)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="submit">    
    <button type="submit" disabled>GO!</button>
  </div>    
</form>
```

Comment: Ok,  but how add submit button with this code